# Problema con el registro en php de los archivos tipo ini de sql servqer

Tags: php, sql, server

He tratado de instalar los archivos de conexion de sql server para php, pero no consigo que php los reconozca o los monte.
Cuando llamo al formulario "info.php" en el subtitulo "PDO" aparece vacio.
Ya copie los archivo suministrado por Microsoft para SQL Server al directorio \ext de php7.4.28
Modifique el archivo php.ini ubicado en el mismo directorio "php7.4.28"
Tengo un formulario de prueba de conexion y me reporta el error:

```
 "'Deprecated: Non-static method Cconexion::conectarBD() should not be called statically in 
 D:\wamp\www\formularios\form_prueba.php on line 31
 No se logró conectar correctamente con la base de datos: PRUEBAS, error: PDOException: could 
 not find driver in D:\wamp\www\formularios\funciones\Conectar.php:15 Stack trace: #0 
 D:\wamp\www\formularios\funciones\Conectar.php(15): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=L...', 
 'sa', 'ppp_000') #1 D:\wamp\www\formularios\form_pruebacombos.php(31): 
 Cconexion::conectarBD() #2 {main}
 Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\wamp\www\formularios\funciones\Conectar.php on line 
 22'"
```

La configuracion que estoy usando es:

- SQL 11.0 x64
- Win 64
- Apache 2.4.2
- PHP 7.4.28 (defecto) y 5.4.3
- Wamp 2.2

Comment: Verifica que el archivo ini que modificaste sea el mismo que indica `phpinfo()` en **Loaded Configuration File**.

Comment: Muchas gracias exactamente estaba modificando otros archivos .ini.